# Where can I find the documentation of `present?` method of ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm studying Rails and have come across some methods which I don't know how to use.

For example, I defined a model `User`. In the `UsersController`, I defined `index` method. In this method, someone used the `@users.present?` method.
I'm not sure what it is. So I want to know how the official site says about it.

Where can I find the explanation of this method.
Could you tell me the way to study methods like this?

Comment: You may have to work on your Google skills – searching for "[rails present?](https://www.google.de/search?q=rails+present%3F)" takes you right to the documentation.

Comment: @Stefan yeah, you're right. I typed the bad keywords. I used `ActiveRecord_Relation present?`. Thanks.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see where specific method is defined, you can check it as follows:

```
@users.method(:present?)
#=> #<Method: User(Object)#present?>
```

This means, that method `present?` is defined in class [`Object`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/Object.html).

Then, when you have a name of the class where method is defined, you just open documentation (either [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/) or [Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)) and search for the method you want to learn about in corresponding class.

In your case, here is documentation for  [`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) method.

Comment: I used bad keywords, so I didn't find what I wanted. Thank you for your exact links